# html, how to make elements not shift when browser zooms?

Tags: html, css

I got a `<div>` containing 2 `<p>`s:

```
#in .html file
<style type="text/css">
    div.box {
        position: relative;
        height: 30px;
    }
    div.box p#id1 {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    div.box p#id2 {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
</style>
...
<div class="box">
    <p id="id1">ID1</p>
    <p id="id2">ID2</p>
</div>
```

When the browser's view is maximized, it looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                           |
|ID1                                                     ID2|
|                                                           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

when I zoom out the browser, it looks like this (**which is not what I want it to be**):

```
---------------------------------
|                               |
|ID1                         ID2|
|                               |
---------------------------------
```

When the browser zooms, the content on the right side (`ID2`) shifts away.
What I expected is that, when I zoom out the browser, the content on the right side should be left out, like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                           |
|ID1                                                     ID2|
|                                                           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------
|                                                         |
|ID1                                                     I|
|                                                         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------
|                               |
|ID1                            |
|                               |
---------------------------------
```

How to do it in Css?

**PS**
The only way I thought of to do the job is to set the `<div>` block's `width` to an explicit number, but how can I know what the width should be, because the screens' size are not the same as mine, right?

Comment: please remember to indicate an answer is accepted if it solved your problem,  Or comment so that we can provide better answers.

Comment: @lostinplace, absolutely I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this style element, it does what you want

```
    <style type="text/css">
        div.box {
            position: relative;
            height: 30px;
            min-width:400px;
        }
        div.box p#id1 {
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 0px;
            display:inline-block;
            float:left;
            clear:none;
        }
        div.box p#id2 {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 0px;
            display:inline-block;
            float:right;
            clear:none;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: could you please explain the `relative` in both `<div>` and `<p>`? I don't quite get it.

Comment: position absolute acts against the window, but position relative acts against the earliest ancestor set to position absolute or position relative

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/dmGqF/2/) jsFiddle. I changed the box width in % to match with the container and used min-width attribute to force it to, not go below certain width.

```
    div.box {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 500px;
    }
    div.box p#id1 {
    float: left;       
    }
    div.box p#id2 {     
    float: right;
    }
```

This may not be what you are looking for, but I believe this would give you some idea.

Hope it helps!